# Displaying system.collections.generic.list 1 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dropbox-api

hey i want to print the member of my dropbox shared folder, i confuse how to show it.

this is my code

```
Private Async Sub ShowMemberToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowMemberToolStripMenuItem.Click
    For Each C As ListViewItem In listfile.SelectedItems


        Dim sharefolder = Await A.Files.GetMetadataAsync(direktori.Text & "/" & C.Text)
        Dim sharedfolderid = sharefolder.AsFolder.SharedFolderId.ToString
        If sharedfolderid = String.Empty Then
            MessageBox.Show("Not Shared Folder")
        Else
            Dim member = A.Sharing.ListFolderMembersAsync(sharedfolderid, limit:=100).Result.Users
            Dim list = String.Join(",", member.ToArray())
            MessageBox.Show(list)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From dropbox [API documention](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#shared-folders) I found this JSON snippet which shows what a `User` is:

```
"membership": [
        {
            "user": {
                "display_name": "Jane P. User",
                "email": "jane@example.com",
                "email_verified": true,
                "member_id": "dbmid:abcd1234"
                "same_team": true,
                "uid": 87654321
            },
            "access_type": "owner",
            "active": true
        },
        ...
    ]
```

So when you're trying to do `Dim list = String.Join(",", member.ToArray())`
 it is has no clue what it is supposed to output unless you override the `ToString` of that class (which isn't worth doing in this case.

What you should do instead, is run a select on `Users` like so:

```
Dim usersOutput = member.Select(Function(m) m.DisplayName)
Dim list = String.Join(",", usersOutput)
```

Comment: with what i should fill (m) ?

Comment: That is an anonymous function where the `m` is each user in the list of users. It is a more compact way to loop through a collection to get what you need

Comment: @AndruDevaLukito Is a Linq statement. Read this [IEnumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)